# ctx.navigateByUrl is not a function Error

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to route my application to another page. I have an app-routing module file and have a path like

```
{
    path: 'compute-savings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tools/computing-tools/compute-savings/compute-savings.module').then( m => m.ComputeSavingsPageModule)
  },
```

The page called compute-savings is generated by the command:

```
ionic generate page
```

So it has all the routing modules and the other necessary files and I already added the module file as a component. I don't know why but other pages working fine but the sub-pages are not working by the meaning of routing. Can anyone explain to me what is I'm doing wrong cause I couldn't find any solution for this?

Comment: Do you see any console errors on this? What do you mean by "I already added the module file as a component."? this sounds wrong to me.

Comment: I mean I forgot to import my ComponentsModule file into the test.module.ts file so basically when the page is called the program doesn't know what to load.